# How to set a Headline for JQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

For my autocomplete I sort my results into 3 sections "title", "company", "tag".
I would like to have a headline for each section.
In practise I want to add `<div class='ui-optionHeader'>Headline</div>` before the li elements, I think.
I cant figure it out, either the headline is above every single element or it doesnt work at all.

I made an visual explanation - This is what I aim for:
[image]

---

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 src = "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
 $("#search_text").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
       $.ajax({
           url: src,
           dataType: "json",
           data: {
               term : request.term,
               searchOption : $("#search_option").val()
           },
           success: function(data) {
               response(data);
           }
       });
     },
   select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#search_text').val(ui.item.value);
  },
  minLength: 1,
  open : function(){
  //  $(".ui-autocomplete:visible").css({top:"+=13"});
  }
 })
  .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

      if(item.option==="title") {
        return $( "<li>" )
          .append( "<div><i class='fas fa-tags'></i> " + item.label + "<br> title </div>" )
          .appendTo( ul );
      }

      else if(item.option==="company"){
        return $( "<li>" )
          .append( "<div><i class='fas fa-building'></i> " + item.label + "<br> company </div>" )
          .appendTo( ul );
      }

      else if(item.option==="tags"){
        return $( "<li>" )
          .append( "<div><i class='fas fa-utensils'></i> " + item.value + "<br> tags </div>" )
          .appendTo( ul );
      }
  };

});
```

What it currently looks like:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please review: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I somehow cant build it together.   
My category value is "item.option". Could you give me an code example?

Comment: Would need a sample of the expected data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
    },
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li;
        if (item.category != currentCategory) {
          ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        if (item.category) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  var data = [{
      label: "anders",
      category: ""
    },
    {
      label: "andreas",
      category: ""
    },
    {
      label: "antal",
      category: ""
    },
    {
      label: "annhhx10",
      category: "Products"
    },
    {
      label: "annk K12",
      category: "Products"
    },
    {
      label: "annttop C13",
      category: "Products"
    },
    {
      label: "anders andersson",
      category: "People"
    },
    {
      label: "andreas andersson",
      category: "People"
    },
    {
      label: "andreas johnson",
      category: "People"
    }
  ];

  $("#search_text").catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: data
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-category {
  background: #009F84;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

form #search {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: .5em;
  width: 75%;
}

form button {
  background: #009F84;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .65em 2em;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="search_text"> <button type="submit">Find</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Worked for me now.

Comment: @iTzMeRafa glad it helped. Hopefully you will want to mark it as the answer.